# Am I using OneToOne relationship right?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

Hello I am actually working on a REST server using Spring-boot, hibernate, psql and I am experiencing some difficulties after adding an OneToOne relationship between  entities.

Here are the 2 entities:

Pays:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pays")
public class Pays implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@JsonProperty("codePays")
private String codePays;

@Column(name = "libelle_pays")
@JsonProperty("libellePays")
private String libellePays;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "pays",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
private Traduction traduction;

protected Pays() {
}

public Pays(String codePays,String libellePays) {
    this.codePays = codePays;
    this.libellePays = libellePays;
}
```

and Traduction:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "traduction")
public class Traduction implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonProperty("codeTrad")
private long codeTrad;

@Column(name = "defaultLanguage")
@JsonProperty("defaultLanguage")
private boolean defaultLanguage;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="fk_code_pays")
@JsonProperty("codePays")
private Pays pays;

public Traduction(){
}

public Traduction(String codePays,boolean defaultLanguage) {
    this.defaultLanguage = defaultLanguage;
    pays.setCodePays(codePays);
}
```

My problem happen when I try to populate my table traduction using a Post method:

```
@PostMapping("/traduction")
public Traduction createTraduction(@RequestBody Traduction trad) {
    System.err.println(trad);
    return repository.save(trad);
}
```

when I send JSON data to my server via PostMan like this:

> {
>       "codeTrad":0,
>       "defaultLanguage":true,
>       "fk_code_pays":"FR"
>       }

or this way:

> {
>       "codeTrad":0,
>       "defaultLanguage":true,
>       "pays":
>       {
>           "codePays":"FR",
>           "libellePays":"France"
>       }
>   }

My server doesn't seem to understand the mapping with the object Pays.
Here what the object Traduction look like after my request: 
[codeTrad=0, null, defaultLanguage=true]

and the pretty error:

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.auchan.corp.ipon.iponportail.model.Traduction["codePays"])]

So I am wondering if the problem comes from my server conception or just my JSON. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace, please.

Comment: @Patrick unfortunately there is nothing more :/

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from :

```
public Traduction(String codePays, boolean defaultLanguage) {
        this.defaultLanguage = defaultLanguage;
        pays.setCodePays(codePays)
```

The pays is null and that's why you get an exception : `java.lang.NullPointerException`, well try to add Pays pays to that constructor.

Comment: You're right I have some other issues but they are due to my conception, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This json won't work:

```
{ "codeTrad":0, "defaultLanguage":true, "fk_code_pays":"FR" }
```

as there is no field name `fk_code_pays` in your `Traduction` class.

Below won't work either:

```
{ "codeTrad":0, "defaultLanguage":true, "pays": { "codePays":"FR", "libellePays":"France" } }
```

Because pays is annotated with `@JsonProperty("codePays")`

As per your DTO classes, your json should be:

```
{ "codeTrad":0, "defaultLanguage":true, "codePays": { "codePays":"FR", "libellePays":"France" } }
```

Also I would recommend you to use wrapper classes in place of primitives. `Boolean` in place of `boolean` and `Long` in place of `long`.